# Unit Test of Spring Boot JMS Application Leaves Messages on Queue

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit4

I have a spring boot JMS application that during startup up loads up multiple WebShpere MQ queues and copies the messages from those queues to another queue. Everything works, but I'm starting some unit testing and I think there a couple things I'm not understanding. So I have a config class that holds a bunch of annotated beans, one of those beans are the class that does the message loading before my JMSListener starts up. I have simple Unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ErrorQueueReportApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "DEV")
public class CastsApplicationTests {

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CastsApplicationTests.class.getName());

    @Value("${hostname}")
    String host;

    @Test
    public void testEcsProps(){
        System.out.println("Running test");
        assertEquals("hostname.someTLD", host);
    }

}
```

This test passes, but I only expected to simply check my `@Value` see that they are equal and done. But running this as a unit test starts up my whole application, and since I have a bean that makes queue connections and loads up a queue, this unit test makes the queue connections and loads up a queue. But then my JMSListener is never kicked off so everything just stays on the queue and I have to manually clear it. This is unacceptable.

From what I understand about Spring Boot, `@SpringApplicationConfiguration()` takes the main class that will have the Application Context and the test runner starts up the application like it normally would. If this is the case I'm not sure how to go about Unit testing if it's going to load up my queue every time and never reads them off. Any suggestions or concepts to clarify to help me see more clearly?

Comment: I'll add more classes etc if needed, but right now I feel like this is more of a lack of understanding problem that may be able to be fixed with some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if this is just a hack around the functionality or if it's just simply the right thing to do. I just set up a `@Before` and an `@After` and basically just clear the queue to ensure what ever the unit test may put on it always takes it off.

If anyone decides to contribute to some knowledge sharing as to what exactly is going on and how to work with the framework more accordingly that would still be appreciated. Otherwise I expect the post to fall to the bottom of the internet never to be seen again.